# Problem with tikz nodes on a simple line,

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, alignment

I would simply like the "Outside Option" label and the "Retailer" Label not to overlap with the segment's extrema!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8]
\draw[-][very thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [thick] (0,-.1) node[below]{0} node[above]{Outside Option} -- (0,0.1);
\draw [thick] (1,-.1) node[below]{1} node[above]{Retailer} -- (1,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Had a look at the past questions, but I couldn't get what am I missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think just move the nodes to after the end coordinate.

Currently you're doing e.g. `(1,-.1) node[above] {Retailer} ...` meaning the node is placed relative to (1, -0.1). If instead you do `(1,-.1) -- (1, 0.1) node[above] {Retailer}` the node is placed relative to (1, 0.1).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8]
\draw[-][very thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [thick] (0,-.1) node[below]{0} -- (0,0.1) node[above]{Outside Option};
\draw [thick] (1,-.1) node[below]{1} -- (1,0.1) node[above]{Retailer};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see!!!